# How to remove timestamp from GridView

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, oracle11g

I populate a textbox with date from a datepicker with `Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();`,
after which I store in an Oracle database with a query shown below

```
string query3 = "insert into leave_module1 values(:srno,:name,:desig,:tol,:compdates,:fd,:td,:nod,:da,:ds,st.nextval)";
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query3, con);
try
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(":srno", OracleType.Number, 8).Value = DropDownList2.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(":name", OracleType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox8.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(":desig", OracleType.VarChar, 30).Value = TextBox10.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(":tol", OracleType.VarChar, 10).Value = DropDownList1.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(":compdates", OracleType.VarChar, 30).Value = TextBox9.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(":fd", OracleType.DateTime).Value = TextBox3.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(":td", OracleType.DateTime).Value = TextBox4.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(":nod", OracleType.Number, 3).Value = TextBox5.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(":da", OracleType.DateTime).Value = TextBox11.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(":ds", OracleType.DateTime).Value = TextBox7.Text;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('The Data has been added');window.location='Default2.aspx';</script>;");
}
catch
{
    Label13.Visible = true;
}
```

But when I populate a GridView in another page with the stored dates, I get a timestamp even though I did not input one. Please tell me how to remove the timestamp from the display!

Thanks in advance

This is how I populate the gridview

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string v = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["harish"].ConnectionString;
    con = new OracleConnection(v);
    con.Open();
    cmd = new OracleCommand("select *  from leave_module1 where srno='"+DropDownList1.Text+"'", con);
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    GridView1.DataSource = dr;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
    dr.Close();
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code for the gridview?

Comment: the select statement and gridview is important. not the insert statement.

Comment: Maybe here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567421/remove-timestamp-from-date-in-c

Comment: OP is surely mentioning about formatting DateTime. ie, [`DateTime.ToString(string format)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx)

Comment: @JasonMeckley:ive posted the display code

Comment: @LolCat: that is only for storing it in the database and not accessing it...thanks anywayz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are querying all the columns from the database and then auto-generating the columns. This is why all the columns are displayed. To resolve this

1. adjust the query to only return the columns that are actually required
2. disable auto-generate columns and define the columns yourself.

rarely do you want to use auto-generated anything, as you loose call control to customize the behavior and output.

Comment: This does not address how to remove timestamp from the GridView, see my answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

Format your data in your query or your code behind (I would do in the query) to remove the timestamp and just show the data.

Comment: how to do that..thats what i dont know :(

Comment: To_Char in your select statement in Oracle, here is a link that should help. http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html

Answer (score 0):

Your specified type in your code is DateTime, so there is a time component whether you specify one or not.  If Oracle has a Date type (I'm not an Oracle guy, but I interface with Oracle on my current project) and you have access to make that change, that is the easiest way to get what you are asking.
Otherwise, You will have to specify .ToShortDateString() (or something equivalent) everytime you use the data to strip off the time component.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit Columns of the GridView, the Fields dialog box will showup. Select the date field for which you want to remove the time portion and enter {0:d} in the DataFormatString property; click OK. When you run your app, your gridview column will show the date part only. This is what worked for me. Converting to Date on the procedure did not work, and formatting on the RowDataBound() handler is a hassle.

[image]